# When using innerHTML to create input type js function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When using innerHTML to create input type problem, I can't rebuild the 
jQuery or javascript function.

like that:
http://jsfiddle.net/tommylylck/gLv9e/

HTML :

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

<button id="block2" onclick="myFunction()">Add Date input</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Javascript with jQuery-UI

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});


function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML='<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>';
}
```

Comment: you never called datepicker on the new input.

Comment: Why are you mixing inline JS with jQuery?

Comment: As Kevin noted, after changing the dom you need to re-initialize jquery plugins/events/functions on them.

Comment: And don't repeat `id`s. And use labels!

Comment: I don't know how to call datepicker with I create the new input

Comment: I update the new ver. to jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/tommylylck/gLv9e/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this answer ([jquery load append datepicker function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102130/jquery-load-append-datepicker-function)) I extrapolate mine.

**HTML:**

```
<p>Date:
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
</p>
<button id="add-datepicker">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

**Javascript (pure JQuery):**

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();

    $("#add-datepicker").click(function () {
        var picker = $("<input/>", {
            type: 'text',
            id: "datepicker" + $("#demo").children().length + 1
        }).datepicker();
        $("#demo").append(picker);
    });
});
```

You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/franverona/Tza5M/

I suggest you not to mix pure Javascript with JQuery because JQuery. You can end your day writing `document.getElementById("datepicker").append($("#button"))` and your browser would explode :)

**Happy coding!**